# How to indent a table?

Tags: tables

I have a doubt, I want to replicate this table, but I am missing the identation part.

[image]

Comment: What you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

[Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Please always add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question.

At risk of shooting in the dark without that MWE, probably you only need add `\indent` before each indented text. If that do not work for some reason (e.g., **the tabular is inside a `table` float**, where the indentation is automatically set to `0pt`) or do you want less or more indentation, you will need set `\parindent` globally (in the preamble) or  partially (in main text) for tabular in main text without floats (that will change also the  indentation of paragraphs after the setting), or locally, before the tabular but inside a group (i.e, a `{...}`) or a environment like a `table` float, that will not change anything outside that group or environment. The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
%\begin{table} 
%\setlength\parindent{3cm} %% Try this with/without table
    \begin{tabular}{ll}
    Panel A. bla bla bla ... &  39,...\\
    \indent Initial sample of bla bla ...    & 24,... \\
    \indent Store bla bla ... & 26,... \\
%\end{table} 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

You can also change `\indent` for any horizontal spacer like `~~~`, `\quad`, `\hspace{1em}`, etc... That will work independently of `\parindent` settings, so if you like the same indentation that in main text paragraphs, check what is `\the\parindent` in main text and be sore o set locally accordingly. Otherwise, `~~~` or so is simpler.

Another way is a add an extra column and use `\multicolumn`  for  rows without indentation. The amount of indentation can be controlled using a `p{<lewngth>}` column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{p{2cm}ll}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{Panel A. bla bla bla ...} &  39,...\\
      & Initial sample of bla bla ...    & 24,... \\
      & Store bla bla ... & 26,... \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `\quad` as the default space at the left of the first column, and override it with `\multicolumn` for the “Panel” lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{Caption}

\begin{tabular}{@{\quad} l c c c c @{\qquad}}
\toprule
& A & B & C & D \\
\midrule
& (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\itshape Panel A\@. Sample Formation} \\
Initial Sample of Store & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
Store Restriction 1. Stores do not Switch Chain \\
$\geq$ 104 weeks & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\itshape Panel B\@. Store Characteristics} \\
Average ... & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another possible starting point:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c>{\raggedright}X cccc}
    \hline
    &       & (1) &  (2) & (3) & (4)                    \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel A: Sample formation}           \\ 
    \hline
    &   Initial sample of ...    
            & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123                     \\
    &   Store ... 
            & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123                     \\
    &   Store restriction 1: Stores do not SwitchChain, $\geq 104$ weeks
            & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123                     \\
    \hline
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Panel B: Store characteristic}       
            & mean & 25th & median & 75th               \\
    \cline{3-6}
    &   Average ...
            & 123 & 123 & 123 & 123                     \\
    &   ...
            & ... & ... & ... & ...                     \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For further help you need to provide an example of document with your table (MWE: Minimal Working Example).